# Hiring manager likes me but wants me to wait until they finish interviewing other candidates

Tags: interviewing, job-search

A company that I was interviewing is telling me that they really like me but I would have to wait for a few weeks until they finish interviewing other candidates.
While I don't want to interrupt their process, is there a way that I can get them to short circuit their process?
I already let one offer pass by (from another company) because it frankly did not check all the boxes. 
I am available immediately but they don't know that yet.

Comment: They're just doing their due diligence.  They like you, but want to make sure there isn't a better fit.  I'd say the best you can do is wait and hope for the best.

Comment: There IS actually a way to get them to fast their process: Call them and ask them what happened with your evaluation, and that you want the final answer / decision. You WILL get an answer. But probably not the answer that you want to hear.

Comment: Sandra K, they did tell me their evaluation. Their evaluation was that they really like me.

Comment: Let's see, you go to the market and you really like something in one shop, but you tell the shop owner that you would like to check a few more shops. Then the owner asks you to "speed up" your shopping around because he has already lost a customer yesterday. What would you do?

Comment: Keep interviewing.  You cannot let the pipe go empty.   The may find a candidate they *like* even more.

Comment: @Chuck They really like you. But there's a chance that in the coming weeks, they find someone else that they _really really_ like. And you will probably not receive an offer in that case. Best to continue looking until you get something more definite. But follow up with this company after a few weeks.

Answer (score 4):

There's really no good way to speed up the process. If you press them, you may seem desperate or even just annoying.

Having to interview all of the candidates is very common and is probably a good practice if the interviews are already lined up. They don't risk missing out on an unexpectedly great candidate with a minimum of effort.

There's only one possible way I can think of to speed them up and that's to have another offer on the table.  And I mean a real offer. In writing, that you actually want.

In other words, keep looking, keep interviewing and remember:

**Unless you get an actual offer in writing, you don't have an offer.** It doesn't matter if the hiring manager and even the CEO tell you they're hiring you. Unless you have an actual offer, keep looking.

Comment: Exactly. This is pretty common in my experience but generally most places try to keep interviews as close together so they don't have weeks between candidates and someone having to wait if they are interested. If you are interested in the job definitely keep the lines of communication open and let them know if you do get another offer you are considering.

Answer (score 2):

Only one thing is clear--they are keeping their options open. You should too. Keep interviewing and get excited about other opportunities. If this one loops back, you can decide when the offer comes through. You have no offer, no terms, nothing to bank on.

If you try to push forward you will lose leverage in salary negotiation and gain nothing in moving them faster. Would you like the job for 20% less than market value?

The fact that you're available right away probably doesn't concern them. They're taking a few more weeks to interview, what's wrong with 2 more for notice?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one thing you can do to speed up their decision process in a favourable way. Find another job.

Once you have another job offer, then it's quite fair to contact them explaining that you have another job offer, that if they are able to make an offer within the next 24 hours it will be looked on favourably, otherwise you will alas, be off the market.

They may say a straight no. If you are their best candidate, they may decide that they don't want to lose you, and shorten the selection process.